# Function to change a label (Username) in a core WordPress File (wp-includes/general-template.php)

Tags: core, username

Would like to change

'label_username' => __( 'Username' ) on line 258 of wp-includes/general-template.php
to
'label_username' => __( 'Username or Email' )

Changing core files is a not recommended  --- never never

So any help to code a function to achieve this would really be appreciated.

Comment: why you want to do that?  we can use filter to alter a function using that variable.

Answer (score 5):

Try putting this in your functions.php

```
function wpse60605_change_username_label( $defaults ){
    $defaults['label_username'] = __( 'Username or Email' );
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'login_form_defaults', 'wpse60605_change_username_label' );
```

Comment: Bravo! Works! and many many thanks to you and the other contributors

Answer (score 1):

You should hook to the `gettext` filter which is called by `__()` function on domain translated text with the untranslated text as second parameter.

Take a look at how to use `gettext` filter for [changing the comment form](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/gettext#Change_the_Comment_Form).

Comment: thanks. going on similar type previous answers i came up with    add_filter( 'gettext', 'change_label');
function change_label($translated_text){
        switch ( $translated_text ) {
            case 'Username' :
                $translated_text = __( 'Username or email', 'theme_text_domain' );
                break;
        }
    return $translated_text; but no go. That being said I am just a copy and paster have no real coding knowledge