# Modify wp-login.php labels: Username to Email

Tags: wp-login-form

How can you edit the labels of the `wp-login.php` form?

I am using emails for logins, so I need to change `username` to `email`.

The answer here seems to be out of date, or just doesn't work with SSL or something: [Function to change a label (Username) in a core WordPress File (wp-includes/general-template.php)](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/60605/function-to-change-a-label-username-in-a-core-wordpress-file-wp-includes-gene)

I tried this in my functions file, but it didn't work:

```
function wpse60605_change_username_label( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['label_username'] = __( 'Email' );
    return $defaults;
}
add_filter( 'login_form_defaults', 'wpse60605_change_username_label' );
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48502233/7186739

Answer (score 6):

Found this here: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-change-the-text-labels-in-userpass-box-on-login-page/

The other answer here didn't work for me, but this one did.

Just in case this helps anyone.

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'register_text' );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'register_text' );
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace(
        'Username or Email Address',
        'Your Custom Text',
        $translated
    );
    return $translated;
}
```

Comment: Like for Carole, the above (chosen answer) did not work for me.  But, this worked! (WordPress version 4.7.x).

Answer (score 3):

Found an answer on stackoverflow shortly after posting this:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825865/change-wordpresss-login-label-username

Uses the gettext filter instead of any wp functions

Comment: Simple solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12825865/change-wordpresss-login-label-username/48502233#48502233

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
add_filter(  'gettext',  'register_text'  );
add_filter(  'ngettext',  'register_text'  );
function register_text( $translating ) {
     $translated = str_ireplace(  'Username or Email Address',  'Your Custom Text',  $translating );
     return $translated;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to changing the login screen, I wanted to remove the Username field from the admin Add New User form. This code added to functions.php did the trick:

```
function hide_username_field(){
    // Hide the username field on the admin Add New User form
    echo "\n" . '<script type="text/javascript">jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(\'input#user_login\').parent().parent().hide();
        $(\'input#email\').change(function() {
            $(\'input#user_login\').val($(\'input#email\').val());
        });
    }); 
    </script>' . "\n";
}
add_action('admin_head','hide_username_field');
```